# How to check if an advertisement has finished in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am using a rewarded video ad from admob in unity. The advertise is called when the player dies and asks them if they want to watch an ad to be revived. I am trying to check when the advertised has finished so I can reward the player.

```
void Update()
{
    if(isCalled == true){
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507";
        RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
        showAd(rewardBasedVideo);
    }
}

public void showAd(RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo)
{
    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        //Subscribe to Ad event
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    string type = args.Type;
    double amount = args.Amount;
    //Reawrd User here
    print("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);

    isCalled = false;

    managerScript.revival();
    managerScript.Loading.SetActive(false);
}
```

The first time the advertised is watched in the scene the method revival is called and the loading screen is closed and everything works fine, after that when the advertise is watched again it does not work, the "HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded" method is not called , a new advertise just pops up to watch over and over. How do i fix it, since the game is not calling the "HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded" method when the ads finish the second time. so the method revival is called and the loading screen is closed like it does on the first time the game is opened.
Note: The issue still happens even when the scene is restarted (not the entire game).

Update:
I have edited the script to your solution but the problem is still occuring. Whay isnt it working?
 Here is the full script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class GameAdvertising : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isCalled;
    public GameObject Manager;
    GameManager managerScript;

    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507";
    RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = null;

    void Start () {
        managerScript = gameObject.GetComponent<GameManager>();

        isCalled = false;

        //Subscribe to Ad event once
        rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        //Subscribe to Ad event once
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;

    }

    public void adButton()
    {
        isCalled = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(isCalled == true){
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
            showAd();
        }
    }

    public void showAd()
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        string type = args.Type;
        double amount = args.Amount;
        //Reawrd User here
        print("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);

        isCalled = false;

        managerScript.revival();
        managerScript.Loading.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely because you registering to event multiple times when you call  `rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;` more than once. You should remove it from there and put it in the Start function instead.

```
string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507";
RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = null;

void Start()
{
    //Subscribe to Ad event once
    rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    //Subscribe to Ad event once
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
}

public void adButton()
{
   AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
   rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
   showAd();
}

void Update()
{

}

public void showAd()
{
    print("IN showAd()");
    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
    {
        print("IN showAd() AND IsLoaded()");
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }else{
        print("IN showAd() NOT IsLoaded()");
     }
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
{
    print("IN HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded()");
    IsLoaded()
    string type = args.Type;
    double amount = args.Amount;
    //Reawrd User here
    print("User rewarded with: " + amount.ToString() + " " + type);


    managerScript.revival();
    managerScript.Loading.SetActive(false);
}

public void OnDestroy()
{
    //Un-Subscribe to Ad event once
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
}
```

Comment: I couldnt fit my reply in here so Ill update the question

Comment: @Physix I modified my answer witth bunch of of print statements. Please copy the new code, run it then update your question with the Log from the print statement the second time the program is run. That I can use to determine what is going bad.

Comment: I just test my app by build and run straight to my samsung A5 through USB, How do i log (Apologies for beginner question).

Comment: @Physix From your computer command line type `adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG`

Comment: @Physix Use the Tool that comes with Android sdk. Loot at the instructions here. Scroll down to the last page for Android log http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/accessing-unity-game-logs/

Comment: I somewhat did it. It says "Cannot make a new rewarded video ad request until previous request has been completed" int tag "AdsUnity". it says "IN showAd()" to "IN showAd() NOT IsLoaded()"

Comment: @Physix I moved `isCalled = false;` to under where `showAd();` is called. Please copy the updated code and report back with new log you got.

Comment: Same message now expect in the app the loading screen is meant to appear but it doesnt now (it is called in the manager script when iscalled is true). The logcat is tiring.

Comment: @Physix I don't even know what I was thinking when made my last comment. Please ignore that. I just rolled back the code. When do you set isCalled to true? I know it is when adButton function is called but when is the adButton function called? Every time?

Comment: No. When the player dies a ui button appears asking them if want to revive, it gets pressed once

Comment: @Physix I modified it again. Removed that code from the Update function and put it where the button callback function is. I also added a function to unsubscribe from the event before a new scene is loaded. Let me know what happens. Check if the log message changed or if it is still the-same.

Comment: @Physix So is this problem fixed? Just saw you asked a new question with the code in this answer...

Comment: I slightly edited the code but yes it is fixed thankyou. However a new dam problem has come up.

Comment: @Physix Will take a look.